# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker cant fix

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

im persian and i dont know english very well ... sorry if i writing bad !
i see this question in this site several time but i cant fix my problem by them , so i ask again this is my code

```
using(DocumentationContext context = new DocumentationContext())
{

    var userInstance = new UserInstance();
        userInstance.UserID = user.UserID;
        userInstance.User = user;
        userInstance.InstanceID = item.InstanceID;
        userInstance.Instance = item;
        userInstance.Code = permission.Code;
        userInstance.Direct = Direct;
        userInstance.BaseCode = BaseCode;
        userInstance.Create = Create;
        userInstance.Edit = Edit;
        userInstance.Delete = Delete;

        context.UserInstances.Add(userInstance);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

it is my last change , i have search a lot and cant find answer , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of or both `item` and `user` came from a different instance of `DocumentationContext`. If you're going to use `using`, then all your entities must be queried, updated, whatever in that same `using` statement.

The better approach for safety-sake is to inject your context as a dependency to your controllers. Then in the setup for whatever DI container you choose to work with, you should be able to give your context a "request scope", which essentially means that it will only ever create one instance per request. That will ensure that you're never working with multiple instances of your context.